# CSS ::before pseudo-element line-height?

Tags: html, pseudo-element, css, css-content

My paragraph has a height/line-height of 50px and `text-align: center`, which centers the text. But p:before is causing it to increase in height/line-height, causing the text to bump down. I want both p and p:before to be vertically centered.

http://jsfiddle.net/MMAUy/

```
<p>Hover This</p>

p {
    background: red;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

p:hover:before {
    content: "icon";
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

The text length varies so I don't think i can just use `position: absolute` for the icon...

Comment: Interesting question. What varies in length? The text on hover, or the actual text before hover?

Comment: I was just saying I can't use position: absolute for the icon because the text won't always be the same, and i need the icon right next to the text.

Comment: Check out this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/MMAUy/1/ I removed the height. Looks like the pseudo-element is adding some height to the box... Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason this occurs, is because `line-height` is being inherited by the `:before` elements, which is also an `inline-block` element.

You could solve this by floating the `:before` content, thus removing it from the flow, rendering it unaffected by the `line-height`.

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/hchNR/)

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <p>Hover This</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    background: red;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align:center;
}

div:hover p:before {
    content: "icon icon icon icon";
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 42px;
    float:left;
}
p {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0px;
}
```

Comment: Good idea with the float. I still wonder if there's a way to accomplish this without adding additional markup?

Answer (score 9):

It's really simple. You should give

`vertical-align: top;`

to the :before element.

Your updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Pz7vF/

Answer (score 0):

Something that worked for me is using !important, as long as you're not already using it in the element.

```
element {
  line-height : 110%;
}

element::before {
  content : "HI";
  line-height : 40px !important;
}
```